# Scope of variable inside switch case

Tags: go, scope

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := 10
    switch x {
    case 0:
        y := 'a'
        fmt.Printf("%c\n", y)
    case 1:
        // y = 'b' // this can't compile,
        y := 'b'
        fmt.Printf("%c\n", y)
    default:
        y := '-'
        fmt.Printf("%c\n", y)
    }
}
```

Seems `y` in each `case` is local to the containing `case`, not visible to other case.
As I know:

- `{}` can create a local scope, but there is no `{}` for each `case`.
- Java is different.

I've searched the internet, didn't get a clear definition. I know we can declare switch scope variable in the `initialization` part of `switch`.

**Questions**:

1. Can you confirm that, in Golang, scope of variable inside switch `case` is local to the case itself?
2. Is this a special design, as mentioned above there is no `{}` for each `case`.

Comment: You wrote: _there is no {} for each case._ But not all blocks are syntactic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spec: Blocks:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blocks)

> A *block* is a possibly empty sequence of declarations and statements within matching brace brackets.
>
> ```
> Block = "{" StatementList "}" .
> StatementList = { Statement ";" } .
> ```
>
> In addition to explicit blocks in the source code, there are implicit blocks:
>
> 1. The *universe* block encompasses all Go source text.
> 2. Each [package](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Packages) has a *package block* containing all Go source text for that package.
> 3. Each file has a *file block* containing all Go source text in that file.
> 4. Each ["if"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#If_statements), ["for"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements), and ["switch"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Switch_statements) statement is considered to be in its own implicit block.
> 5. **Each clause in a ["switch"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Switch_statements) or ["select"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements) statement acts as an implicit block.**
>
> Blocks nest and influence scoping.

As you can see in the spec: each clause (e.g. `case`) acts as an implicit block without explicitly using `{}`.

Comment: In item `5`, regarding `Each clause`, it means `case` and `default` I suppose.

Comment: @Eric Yes, correct. Again, check the spec for exact definition: [Spec: Switch statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Switch_statements)